# trying to connect the login and database connection classes so that i can execute sql statements in the login.java file

Tags: java, swing, class, authentication, derby

My code is in different folders and thus different packages. I am having difficulty connecting my `login.java` with my `database_connection.java` file.

I want the form and the database connection class to be separate but still be able to access the database.

The `login.java` file is a Java Swing file. It is my `View`. The `Database_Connection.java` is supposed to be my `Controller`. Similar to what you would do in web development. I want to just have the connection details in a separate class from the front end.

login.java:

```
package View;

import Controller.Database_Connection;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

   public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    /*** Creates new form Login */
    public Login() 
    {
        initComponents();

        //static Connection Conn = null;
        //PreparedStatement Query = null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        form_username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        form_password = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        btn_login_cancel = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        btn_login_enter = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("LOGIN ");

        jLabel2.setText("USERNAME: ");

        jLabel3.setText("PASSWORD:");

        btn_login_cancel.setText("CANCEL");
        btn_login_cancel.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_login_cancelActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn_login_enter.setText("ENTER");
        btn_login_enter.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_login_enterActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(200, 200, 200)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(form_username))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(btn_login_cancel)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                        .addComponent(btn_login_enter))
                                    .addComponent(form_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))))
                .addGap(84, 84, 84))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(form_username, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(form_password, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn_login_cancel)
                    .addComponent(btn_login_enter))
                .addContainerGap(46, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn_login_enterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try
        {
            //The code below is to capture the text input from the login frame input fields
            String username = form_username.getText();
            String password = form_password.getText();

            //Flag to be used to validdate login credentials
            int correct_credentials;

            //Make a connection to the database conncection class
            Database_Connection.ConnectDB();

            //Perform the SQL Commands
            String Query1 = "SELECT Username,Password FROM Users WHERE Username ='"+username+"'AND Password ='"+password+"'";

            PreparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(Query1);
        }    
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        //Check if field equals to blank and throw error message
        if (username.equals("")|| password.equals(""))
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Name or Password is empty!! ","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (username.endsWith(Query1) && password.endsWith(Query1))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," ");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your Login Credentials are Invalid!");
        }

    }                                               

    private void btn_login_cancelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        close();
    }                                                

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        //Conn = Sqlite_Database_Connection.ConnectDB();
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                new Login().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton btn_login_cancel;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton btn_login_enter;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField form_password;
    private javax.swing.JTextField form_username;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void close()
    {
        //This is a statement to use to close the current window
        WindowEvent winClosing = new WindowEvent(this,WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(winClosing);
    }

}
```

Database_Connectioin.java:

```
package Controller;

import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Database_Connection 
{
    private Connection connect;

    public static Connection ConnectDB()
    {
        // The URL to the Java Derby Server
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1739`enter code here`/TEST_DB";


        try
        {
            Connection connect;
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL,"###","####");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Connection Successful");

            return connect;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database Connection Not Successful");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Database_Connection() {
        this.connect = null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the connect
     */
    public Connection getConnect() 
    {
        return connect;
    }

    /**
     * @param connect the connect to set
     */
    public void setConnect(Connection connect) 
    {
        this.connect = connect;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], go through the [help] and read [ask], please clarify your question as it's unclear what you're asking right now. Also follow Java naming conventions `firstWordLowerCaseVariable`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `FirstWordUpperCaseClass`, `ALL_WORDS_UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`. Packages should be all lowercase too.

Comment: thank you, i'll do just that